# Documents created by GAS not returning in search results

Tags: google-apps-script

I've written a script that converts documents from my company's old document system into Google Drive as a google document. However, when searching in My Drive for words that I know are in these documents, they are not returned in the list of results. If I open one of these documents and edit it, it may then return as a result in future searches.

I've been able to reproduce this with a small script

```
function newDoc() {
  var title = "Document Search Testing ";
  var txt = "You can't handle the truth! Son, we live in a world that has walls, and those walls have to be guarded by men with guns. Who's gonna do it? You? You, Lieutenant Weinberg? I have a greater responsibility than you can possibly fathom! You weep for Santiago and you curse the Marines. You have that luxury. You have the luxury of not knowing what I know: that Santiago's death, while tragic, probably saved lives. And my existence, while grotesque and incomprehensible to you, saves lives! You don't want the truth, because deep down in places you don't talk about at parties, you want me on that wall! You need me on that wall! We use words like honor, code, loyalty. We use these words as the backbone of a life spent defending something. You use them as a punchline! I have neither the time nor the inclination to explain myself to a man who rises and sleeps under the blanket of the very freedom that I provide, and then questions the manner in which I provide it! I would rather you just said Thank you, and went on your way. Otherwise, I suggest you pick up a weapon, and stand a post. Either way, I don't give a damn what you think you are entitled to!";
  for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
    var doc = DocumentApp.create(title + i);
    doc.appendParagraph(txt);
    doc.appendParagraph(" ");
    doc.appendParagraph("the end");
    doc.saveAndClose();
  }
  "done";
}
```

I also then manually created a document called 'Document Search Testing Manual' and pasted that same movie quote into it. I then searched My Drive using the search term 'weapon' and received the following results:

```
9/11@10:47 Created via script
  Document Search Testing 0
  Document Search Testing 1
  Document Search Testing 2
9/11@10:50 manually created (copied text)
  Document Search Testing Manual
9/11@10:52 searched on 'weapon', only hit is the script document
9/11@11:38 searched on 'weapon', receive hits for the script itself and the manual document none of the script created ones
9/11@14:00 searched on 'weapon', hits for the script and the manual document only
9/12@10:00 searched on 'weapon', hits for the script and the manual document only
9/12@10:01 opened 'Document Search Testing 0', clicked around in document, made no changes, closed document
9/12@10:02 opened 'Document Search Testing 1', added a line to the first paragraph, closed document
9/12@10:05 searched on 'weapon', receive hits for the script document, manual document, and Testing 1. Testing 0 and Testing 2 are still not found
9/12@17:40 searched on 'weapon', receive hits for the script document, manual document, and Testing 1. Testing 0 and Testing 2 are still not found
```

Is there something else that I should be doing when creating docs via script to have them indexed for the search. I've looked around the documentation and don't see anything.

Comment: can you share the code you used?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug, and it looks like you've already filed [an issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1841) for this problem.